# Using Latex in Inkscape 1.0 Beta on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, latex, inkscape, vector-graphics, runtime-error

I recently updated my MacOS to Catalina, with that, Inkscape 0.92.2 using XQuartz or X11 stopped working. Since I use Inkscape to make all my figures for conference papers and things like that, I decided to download the new Inkscape 1.0 Beta for Mac which runs natively, and is much better overall. The only problem is that the latex extension doesn't seem to work anymore and I need it to efficiently make figures. When I run the latex extension, I get the following warning:

> "Inkscape has received additional data from the script executed. The
>   script did not return and error, but this may indicate the results
>   will not be as expected."

The warning is this followed by this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdflatex.py", line 75, in <module>
    LatexGenerate().run()
  File "/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/base.py", line 111, in run
    self.save_raw(self.effect())
  File "/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/extensions.py", line 155, in effect
    for child in fragment:
  File "pdflatex.py", line 53, in generate
    G=True, pdf_poppler=True, export_type="svg")
  File "/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/command.py", line 190, in inkscape
    return call(INKSCAPE_EXECUTABLE_NAME, svg_file, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/command.py", line 182, in call
    return _call(program, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/command.py", line 172, in _call
    process.returncode, stderr, stdout, args))
inkex.command.ProgramRunError: Return Code: 1: b'Unknown option -G\n'
b''
args: ['/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/MacOS/inkscape', '--export-file=/var/folders/pf/sqqwth9x1zvghm1pz61mp1r80000gn/T/inktmp6stavbpk/output.svg', '--pdf-page=1', '-G', '--pdf-poppler', '--export-type=svg', '--without-gui', '/var/folders/pf/sqqwth9x1zvghm1pz61mp1r80000gn/T/inktmp6stavbpk/input.pdf']
```

And nothing happens. Is there any other extension that works with Inkscape 1.0 beta or is there some way to fix this so that I can use Latex in Inkscape again?

Comment: x-post https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/130154/using-latex-in-inkscape-1-0-beta-on-macos-catalina

Answer (score 2):

"The EQTeXSVG extension (Render > LaTeX) that could be used to convert an inline LaTeX equation into SVG paths using Python was dropped, due to its external dependencies."
http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/1.0#Inline_LaTeX_formula_conversion_dropped

Comment: I'm not sure that thats the extension that I'm using, there seem to be multiple extensions for entering LaTeX into Inkscape, e.g. TexText, LaTexText. Also, the location was similar but not the same (Render > Mathematics > LaTeX (pdflatex) ...) so perhaps it is another extension. In any case, I figure there's gotta be some other extension or way to fix this since the ability to enter mathematical equations efficiently is a big part of how people use Inkscape.

Comment: Also, checking out the "EQTeXSVG extension" on GitHub here https://github.com/julienvitard/eqtexsvg you can see that the only files for this extension are eqtexsvg.py and eqtexsvg.inx and haven't been modified in over 5 years. The warning message I received referenced a file "pdflatex.py", seemingly a different extension.